# How To Add Methods to Html5 Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am working on a project using Html5 canvas , i want to add methods to Canvas Object . Something Like This ...

```
HtmlCanvas.alert = function() { alert("width : " + this.width + ", height : " + this.height) }; // adding method
var canvas1 = document.getElementById("myCanvas1"); // getting canvas1
canvas1.width = 200; // setting width
canvas1.height = 200; // setting height

var canvas2 = document.getElementById("myCanvas2"); // getting canvas1
canvas2.width = 100; // setting width
canvas2.height = 100; // setting height

canvas1.alert(); // alert info
canvas1.alert(); // alert info
```

Comment: I'd think you'd want to create a "class" that contains a reference to a canvas object, instead.  IOW, use composition, not extension.

Comment: Unless it's for a class homework, do not listen to the wither-than-white sirens, and just go on adding methods to CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype. Javascript has enough flaws not to use its flexibility. Changing a prototype is perfectly 'legal', and i was not (?yet?) transformed into a toad for using this.

Comment: @GameAlchemist: Me too...ribit, ribit, ribit :)   I add to prototypes all the time, but I rarely change existing methods--bad Karma!

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend not to try to extend native objects of web browsers.

- It is very bad programming practice to stick new functions to classes which are out of your control. It decreases the maintainability of the code base.
- Web security might not like the idea you messing with native objects prototypes
- You cannot guarantee Canvas API stays as the same in the future browsers and thus your functions might clash with the future browsers

Instead use encapsulation or proxy design proxy patterns and write your own Canvas class wrapper where you can add your own methods.

More about the matter in this (almost related) question:

[Subclassing CanvasRenderingContext2D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20435455/subclassing-canvasrenderingcontext2d/20458813#20458813)

However if you want to do it after all this discouragement adding new functions to existing JavaScript objects is easy as:

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas1");

c.alert = function() {
     alert("xxx");
}


c.alert();
```

Comment: -1 : the aversion to prototype changes is a message that sells well, and might apply for *some* changes, in a 300,000 lines of code project that was built to last for 10 years or more. For 99.9999% of the changes, it's quite as relevant as to say : 'don't rely on html specs, they might change'.

Comment: eh I dont agree with the downvote. For what the OP is trying to do extending the canvas seems silly.

Comment: i explained my downvote, other S.O. members might support your view. I had enough right-perfect answers with zero votes, and plain-stupid answers accepted with 10 upvotes to say it's fair :-)

Comment: @GameAlchemist: Don't take S.O. droids too seriously. I also received "Unsung hero" golden badge for my zero votes answers ;)